# Razor - @Html.DropDownList com name dinamico

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Eu gostaria de concatenar o ID que eu pego do @Model na string da propriedade *name* do Dropdownlist, pois gostaria de tratá-los dinamicamente.

Eu tento fazer @Html.DropDownList("Nome" + @Model.Id) e não funciona.

Como eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Faça isso em seu Model:

```
public string ConcatenarNome 
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("Nome{1}", Id);
        }
    }
```

E depois na View:

```
@Html.DropDownList(@Model.ConcatenarNome)
```